# C# variable assignment can not be obtained

Tags: c#

```
public void textServername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _sn = textServername.Text;
}

public static string connectionString =  _sn ;
```

connectionString Why can't get the assignment of _sn

Comment: What is the exact message you're getting? My guess is that `_sn` is an instance field, and not a static field. Since you haven't shown the declaration of `_sn`, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Where did you define `_sn`? Please provide the definition of `_sn`.

Comment: But no matter what the definition of `_sn` is, static variables will be initialized before any instance methods run, so `connectionString` will not be updated along with `_sn` when `textServername_TextChanged()` runs

Comment: public static string _sn;

Comment: Full error message, please.

Comment: public static string _sn;
 public void textServername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _sn = textServername.Text;

        }

public static string connectionString =  _sn ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although string is a reference type, it acts like a value type.
When connnectionString is initialized , it gets the value of _sn at the time of initialization. Updating the value of _sn would not be reflected by conntectionString. If you want value to be reflected, you can use a property instead like below.

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
    get => _sn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use static constructor.A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed only once. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static variable that must be initialized at run time.
    static string ConnectionString ;

    // Static constructor is called at most one time, before any
    // instance constructor is invoked or member is accessed.
    static SimpleClass()
    {
        ConnectionString = "connection string";
    }
}
```